# How to return the elements around another element in a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist, python-requests

I'm trying to return the elements that form a square around another specific element. For example :

> square_ele('j', [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']])

Should return the elements that form a square around 'j':

> ['e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'n', 'o']

I tried to return element[ele-1]/element[ele+1]... and stuff like that but it doesn't work.
Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Could you please be more clear?  what is a square in this case? what is `element`? and `ele` ?

Comment: element like : for element in list1, and ele like: for ele in element. And the square is the indexes that are horizontally, vertically and diagonally adjacent to the specific element

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
def f(letter, lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for j in range(len(lst[i])):
            if lst[i][j] == letter:
                return lst[i-1][j-1:j+2] + [lst[i][j-1]] + [lst[i][j+1]] + lst[i+1][j-1:j+2]
```

Comment: it doesn't return the diagonals

Comment: My bad! Should be fixed now

Answer (score 1):

1. find the target by searching the grid elements one by one, and obtain its coordinates
2. interate over its neighbours by coordinates and don't forget to skip neighbour that does not exist (e.g. the letter 'a' has only three neighbours)

```py
def square_ele(tgt, grid):
    tgt_x, tgt_y = -1, -1
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(grid):
        for col_idx, element in enumerate(row):
            if element == tgt:
                tgt_x, tgt_y = row_idx, col_idx
    neighbour = []
    for row_offset in range(-1, 2):
        for col_offset in range(-1, 2):
            # skip target itself
            if row_offset == 0 and col_offset == 0:
                continue
            # when target sits on the corners skip neighbour that does not exist
            if tgt_x + row_offset < 0 or tgt_x + row_offset > len(grid):
                continue
            if tgt_y + col_offset < 0 or tgt_y + col_offset > len(grid[0]):
                continue

            neighbour.append(grid[tgt_x + row_offset][tgt_y + col_offset])
    return neighbour
```

Comment: Could you please be More Specific about your goal(s) by providing a very simple example(s)!?! This is called a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: my code return the same as the question requires

Answer (score 1):

If it is guaranteed that your square will always be formed from a subset of the lowercase alphabet, and that for every letter `l` and its index `i` in the flattened square, `i = len(flat_square) - 1 | flat_square[i+1] = alphabet[i+1]`:

```
import string
def square_vals(v, square):
   x, y = (k:=string.ascii_lowercase.index(v))//(l:=len(square[0])), k%l
   if x:
      yield from square[x-1][y-1:y+2]
   yield from [*square[x][y-1:y], *square[x][y+1:y+2]]
   if x+1 < len(square):
      yield from square[x+1][y-1:y+2]
  
print(list(square_vals('j', [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p']])))
```

Output:

```
['e', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'k', 'm', 'n', 'o']
```